# Using a variable to determine sorting type of files in a directory

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a directory of files selected by the user and I need to sort the files inside the directory based on the user's choice. So a form is meant to allow the user to select what to sort the files by from a drop down menu, but the problem is, I need to use the variable in place of the "Name, or LastWriteTime" in the code:

```
var sortedFiles = new DirectoryInfo(selectedPath)
                          .GetFiles(fileTypeTextBox.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                          .OrderBy(f => f."Variable Based On Selected Index of Drop Down")
                          .ToList();
```

It's hard to explain what I want for lack of knowledge on terminology but hopefully you can understand, what I mean.

Also, I am doing this in Visual Studio Express 2013, in C#

Comment: How far you want to go with selecting field by dropdown? (Cheap option obvioulsy to just have sorting function mapped to selection and pass it to `OrderBy`, but you probably looking for fancier expression tree builder or something like that)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm fine with the easy option as long as it functions fine, I'm not very experienced in C# so whatever works is fine, but a link to a tutorial or an explanation would be great if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use if/else statements. e.g.

```
if(dropdown1.value == name){
    .GetFiles(fileTypeTextBox.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                      .OrderBy(f => f.Name)
                      .ToList();
}
else if(dropdown1.value == Created){
    .GetFiles(fileTypeTextBox.Text, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                      .OrderBy(f => f.CreationTime)
                      .ToList();
}
```

etc.

Is that what you were asking?